# Opendkim Key Not Secure

Tags: postfix, ssl, mail

Ubuntu 20, cannot get opendkim-testkey to pass for the life of me. Checked all dependencies, configs numerous times, any help appreciated.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
TEST
-----------------------------------------------------------------
opendkim-testkey -d (domain-name).net -s mail2 -vvv
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: key loaded from /etc/opendkim/keys/(domain-name).net/mail2.private
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'mail2._domainkey.(domain-name).net'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK


-----------------------------------------------------------------
PERMISSIONS:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/postfix/main.cf
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root postfix
-rw-r--r-- root root main.cf
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/postfix/master.cf
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root postfix
-rw-r--r-- root root master.cf
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/opendkim.conf
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
-rw-r--r-- root root opendkim.conf
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     etc
drwxr-xr-x opendkim opendkim opendkim
-rw-r----- opendkim opendkim KeyTable
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     etc
drwxr-xr-x opendkim opendkim opendkim
-rw-r----- opendkim opendkim SigningTable
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     etc
drwxr-xr-x opendkim opendkim opendkim
-rw-r----- opendkim opendkim TrustedHosts
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/opendkim/keys/(domain-name).net/mail.private
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     etc
drwxr-xr-x opendkim opendkim opendkim
drwx------ opendkim opendkim keys
drwx------ opendkim opendkim (domain-name).net
-rwx------ opendkim opendkim mail.private
-----------------------------------------------------------------
f: /etc/opendkim/keys/(domain-name).net/mail.txt
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     etc
drwxr-xr-x opendkim opendkim opendkim
drwx------ opendkim opendkim keys
drwx------ opendkim opendkim (domain-name).net
-rwx------ opendkim opendkim mail.txt



-----------------------------------------------------------------
USERS
-----------------------------------------------------------------
cat /etc/group | grep opendkim
mail:x:12:mail,postfix,opendkim
opendkim:x:120:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
cat /etc/group | grep postfix
mail:x:12:mail,postfix,opendkim
postfix:x:118:


-----------------------------------------------------------------
CONFIGS
-----------------------------------------------------------------
grep "^[^#;]" /etc/opendkim.conf
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes
LogWhy                  yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/relaxed
Mode                    sv
KeyFile         /etc/opendkim/keys/(domain-name).net/mail2.private
UMask                   002
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
KeyTable        refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
-----------------------------------------------------------------
grep "^[^#;]" /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/(domain-name)/STAR_(domain-name)_net.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/(domain-name)/STAR_(domain-name)_net.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/(domain-name)/STAR_(domain-name)_net.ca-bundle
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail2.(domain-name).net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.(domain-name).net, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = (ip of internal relay server)
mynetworks = (all local public and private related networks)
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891

-----------------------------------------------------------------
grep "^[^#;]" /etc/postfix/master.cf
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
postconf -n

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, mail2.(domain-name).net, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail2.(domain-name).net
mynetworks = (all local public and private related networks)
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = (ip of internal relay server)
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/(domain-name)/STAR_(domain-name)_net.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/(domain-name)/STAR_(domain-name)_net.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/(domain-name)/STAR_(domain-name)_net.ca-bundle
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
-----------------------------------------------------------------

netstat -nl | grep 8891
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8891          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: First hit when searching for [opendkim-testkey: key not secure](https://www.google.com/search?q=opendkim-testkey%3A+key+not+secure) gave me [opendkim-testkey: key not secure, but dnssec is ok](https://serverfault.com/questions/834576/opendkim-testkey-key-not-secure-but-dnssec-is-ok) which seems to be a good fit to your question. In short: your domaoin is not (properly) protected by DNSSec.

Comment: Also please note there is no version 20. It must either be 20.04 or 20.10

Comment: 20.04, forgot about specifying that.